# Como desencriptar una cadena

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hola a todos tengo una funcion que encripta la contraseña usando sha1, y lo hace perfecto, lo que ahora no se como desencriptarla, alguien pudiera ayudarme, este es mi codigo para encriptar:

```
  public static string EncryptPassWord(string passwd)
    {
        byte[] temp;           
        SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        temp = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passwd));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(temp[i].ToString("x2"));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

para la cadena = "test" me devuelve a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3 quisiera que cuando enviara esa cadena larga me devuelva "test".

Comment: No es posible aplicar el algoritmo de SHA1 a la inversa para obtener la contraseña.

Comment: Gracias Diego buscare otras alternativas para esto

Comment: Eso no es encripción es una digestión, y no es necesario que le saques reversa simplemente cuando tecleen el password obtienes la digestión y la comparas con la que tengas guardada.

Comment: pues el tema es que tenia un password de un servidor sql guardado en BD encriptado y lo necesitaba para autenticarme en dicho servidor, por eso me hacia falta desencriptar para autenticarme